# what is the best layout can I use it?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have a layout which depends on constraint layout.
The result was very good in one device , but when in change the screen size to see it in multi devices and multi screen Obs !The layout was destroyed .

So ,
What is the best way to get the layout to support all screen sizes without being destroyed?

**This is the xml code**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/b11"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="196dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_book5" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="68dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="132dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView6"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_book1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="104dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_book3" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="132dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="136dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView9"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView7"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/winner"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_book4" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="104dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="80dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView7"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_book2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/winner"
        android:layout_width="78dp"
        android:layout_height="117dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView7"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_winner"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-34dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/start"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="128dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView5"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_startt" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="104dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="116dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView10"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.954"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_book6" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="61dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/winner"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_book7" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView8"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView6"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView6"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_book8" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView9"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="228dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView7"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/winner"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_book9" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView10"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="116dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView9"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_book10" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[This is the layout which I want to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxeg8.jpg)

[and this is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPFCF.jpg)

Comment: please update the question with the result

Comment: I care to your notes and i edit the question

Comment: Best is though Constraint Layout, but here are a few suggestions I would like to make in this, use margin and absolute difference very less. Make use of constraint layout and it's feature more. Make use of chains, guidelines, barriers and other properties. Check [here](https://blog.mindorks.com/using-constraint-layout-in-android-531e68019cd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use constrainlayout guidelines to resolve varying screen sizes issue .**

Below you find your xml file updated to resolve different screen sizes issue using guidelines.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guideline3"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_book5" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guideline7"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_book1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guideline17"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guideline9"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_book3" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guideline13"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guideline6"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_book4" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guideline14"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/guideline1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_book2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/winner"
        android:layout_width="78dp"
        android:layout_height="117dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guideline16"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guideline3"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/start"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guideline5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guideline6"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_startt" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guideline12"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guideline6"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_book6" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guideline15"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guideline1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_book7" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView8"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guideline11"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guideline1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_book8" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView9"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guideline15"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guideline9"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_book9" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView10"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guideline18"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guideline8"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_book10" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.15" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.21" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.36" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.43" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.78" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.82" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.78" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.71" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.55" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline13"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.36" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline15"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.23" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline16"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.14" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline14"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.42" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline18"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.44" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.86" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline17"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.87" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

You can learn in detail about the guidelines from here

https://constraintlayout.com/basics/guidelines.html

As far as handling image sizes for different screens, you can create different image files for different sizes.

```
res/drawable-mdpi/graphic.png         // bitmap for medium-density
res/drawable-hdpi/graphic.png         // bitmap for high-density
res/drawable-xhdpi/graphic.png        // bitmap for extra-high-density
res/drawable-xxhdpi/graphic.png       // bitmap for extra-extra-high-density
```

Answer (score -1):

so after seeing your images there seems to be a path in the background. basically you need to position all your little ic_book images **relative to that path image** (which for some reason I cant find in the list of views) and not relative to each other like you are doing. You probably want to use `ConstraintLayout` but try to replicate the behaviour of the deprecated `RelativePercentLayout` so you can express positions as percentages of your path image. [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html) is an example of how to do that using guidelines (as also suggested above).

Comment: the images are in the linkes above